# Show something is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

During class we noted, that $10^{10^{10^n}}+10^{10^n}+10^n-1$ is not prime for $n>1$. I have a hard time seeing this. What I understand is that $10^n-1$ is clearly dividable by 9. Thus at first I thought I can argue that the whole expression is dividable by 9. However I am having a really hard time, I would appreciate if someone can help me a bit.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It is not true that it is divisible by 9. Notice that $10^k \equiv 1\ (\mod 9)$ always, implying the expression is $\equiv 2\ (\mod 9)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $n = 2^r m$ with odd $m$, then that number $10^{10^{10^n}} + 10^{10^n} + 10^n - 1$ is divisible by $10^{2^r} + 1$ so it can't be prime. (The remainders become $1 + 1 - 1 - 1 = 0.$)

Comment: When we write $n=2^rm$ we assume that $n$ is not a prime. I am not sure how this will play out if $n$ was a prime.

Comment: $r$ can be $0$ if necessary